# How to get the current connection url?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I am using spring jdbc. How can I get the current Connection object for an Oracle database? I'm using connection pooling with JBOSS Wildfly server. I am getting the connection url in my DaoImp by using this code:

```
Connection con;
            try {
                con = getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection();
                dataSource.getConnection().getMetaData().getURL();
                connectionUrl = con.getMetaData().getURL();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

If I write the same code in the setJdbcTemplate method then I am not getting connections over there.There error as follows

> No managed connections available within configured blocking timeout (0
>   [ms])
>   my setJdbcTemplate method as follwos

```
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource){
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        setJdbcTemplate(new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource));
        setNamedParamdbcTemplate(new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(this.dataSource));
        if(connectionUrl==null){
        Connection con;
            try {
                con = getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection();
                connectionUrl = con.getMetaData().getURL();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the max and min connection pool size in the  -ds.xml file.

```
<!--pooling parameters-->
<min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
<max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
<blocking-timeout-millis>5000</blocking-timeout-millis>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increase blocking timeout in ds.xml file. see [configure data source in JBOSS](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Connectors_on_JBoss-Configuring_JDBC_DataSources.html)

> blocking-timeout-millis : This element specifies the maximum time in
>   milliseconds to block while waiting for a connection before throwing
>   an exception. Note that this blocks only while waiting for a permit
>   for a connection, and will never throw an exception if creating a new
>   connection takes an inordinately long time. The default is 5000.

[Default values](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/beta500/html/ch13s04s03s01.html)

> - the length of time to wait for a
>   connection to become available when all the connections are checked
>   out (default 5000 == 5 seconds, from 3.2.4 it is 30000 == 30 seconds)

```
<blocking-timeout-millis>5000</blocking-timeout-millis>
```

Comment: may I know what this <blocking-timeout-millis> will do

Comment: add to answer more details